Test if the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin n}{n}(1+\frac{1}{2}+\dots+\frac{1}{n})$ converges
$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin n}{n}(1+\frac{1}{2}+\dots+\frac{1}{n})$$
Distributing we have
$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\Bigl(\frac{\sin n}{n}+\frac{\sin n}{2n}+\dots+\frac{\sin n}{n^2}\Bigr)$$
The n-th partial sum of the series is
$$ S_n  = (\sin 1) + (\frac{\sin 2}{2} + \frac{\sin 2}{4}) + (\frac{\sin 3}{3} + \frac{\sin 3}{6} + \frac{\sin 3}{9}) + \dots + (\frac{\sin n}{n} + \dots + \frac{\sin n}{n^2})$$
$$\require{cancel}\xcancel{= \underbrace{n(\sin1)}_{\to \infty \text{ as } n\to \infty} + (n-1)\frac{\sin 2}{4}+\dots+2\cdot\frac{\sin (n-1)}{n(n-1)}+\underbrace{1\cdot\frac{\sin n}{n^2}}_{\to 0 \text{ as } n\to \infty}}$$
So as $n \to \infty$ the "first" terms approach $\infty$ and the "last" terms approach $0$, therefore the series diverges. But I'm not sure how to properly state this, which makes me wonder whether there's a more a straightforward way to solve this.

Dirichlet's test

Hint: use Dirichlet's test with $a_n=\frac{1}{n}\left(1+\frac{1}{2}+\ldots+\frac{1}{n}\right)$ and $b_n=\sin n$.

Your evaluation of the partial sums is not correct.. check it; actually the series converges

@Cyankite thanks. I believe I corrected it.

@Gary thanks. I tried what you said in the answer below, take a look if you can

Using the hints from the comments:
Let $a_n=\frac{1}{n}\left(1+\frac{1}{2}+\ldots+\frac{1}{n}\right)$.
Then $$\require{cancel}\xcancel{\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} a_n = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \Bigr(\frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{2n}+ \ldots + \frac{1}{n^2}\Bigl) = 0}$$
Also, $a_n$ is monotonically increasing since all the summands are positive.
It's been shown in the comments by @Gary that the sequence is bounded: $a_n \leq \frac{\pi}{\sqrt {6n}}$, taking the limit of both sides we get $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} a_n \leq 0$ and if we  show that it's monotonically decreasing then, since $0 < a_n$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$, we'll get $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} a_n = 0$.
To show $a_n \geq a_{n+1}$ we do the following
$$\begin{align}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} &= \frac{\frac{1}{n+1}\left(1+\frac{1}{2}+\ldots+\frac{1}{n+1}\right)}{\frac{1}{n}\left(1+\frac{1}{2}+\ldots+\frac{1}{n}\right)}=\frac{{n}\left(1+\frac{1}{2}+\ldots+\frac{1}{n+1}\right)}{(n+1)\left(1+\frac{1}{2}+\ldots+\frac{1}{n}\right)}\\&=\frac{{n}\left(1+\frac{1}{2}+\ldots+\frac{1}{n+1}\right)}{n \left(1+\frac{1}{2}+\ldots+\frac{1}{n}\right) + \underbrace{\left(1+\frac{1}{2}+\ldots+\frac{1}{n}\right)}_{\geq \frac{n}{n+1}\implies 1\geq \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}}}\leq 1\end{align}$$
therefore, $a_n$ is monotonically decreasing, and the above said holds.
Now let $b_n=\sin n$, then we have
$$|B_n| = |\sin 1 + \sin 2 + \ldots + \sin n|=\Bigr|\frac{\sin\frac{n}{2}\sin \frac{n+1}{2}}{\sin \frac{1}{2}}\Bigl|=\frac{\overbrace{|\cos \frac{1}{2}-\cos\frac{2n+1}{2}|}^{\leq 2}}{\sin \frac{1}{2}}\leq \frac{2}{\sin \frac{1}{2}}$$
thus $B_n$ is bounded.
Therefore by Dirichlet's criterion the series converges.

The way you compute the limti of $a_n$ is incorrect. With that argument, we would have $\lim 1 = \lim \left( {\frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{n} +  \ldots  + \frac{1}{n}} \right) = 0 + 0 +  \ldots  + 0 = 0$. How could $a_n$ increase if $a_1=1$ and $a_n\to 0$? Dirichlet's criterion necessarily requires $a_n$ to decrease monotonically. From the positivity of terms, you cannot deduce anything about the nature of monotonicity.

@Gary ah yes, it makes no sense to be increasing...ok I'll give it another go, many thanks

@Gary I then don't understand how this limit is supposed to approach $0$ edit: got it. do you have a hint perhaps?

$$
na_n  = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\frac{1}{k}}  = 1 + \sum\limits_{k = 2}^n {\int_{k - 1}^k {\frac{{{\rm d}t}}{k}} }  \le 1 + \sum\limits_{k = 2}^n {\int_{k - 1}^k {\frac{{{\rm d}t}}{t}} }  = 1 + \int_1^n {\frac{{{\rm d}t}}{t}}  = 1 + \log n
$$ Why would $a_1=1$ imply that $a_n$ cannot tend to $0$?

Another way: $$
\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\frac{1}{k}}  \le \sqrt {\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\frac{1}{{k^2 }}} }  \le \sqrt {\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{k^2 }}} }  = \frac{\pi }{{\sqrt {6n} }}
$$

@Gary ah I see, nice. thanks again

@Gary also, would this be enough? $$\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\frac{1}{k}} \le \frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{k^2 }}}  = \frac{\pi^2 }{{ {6n} }}$$
I'm wondering if you needed to take the sqrts, or was that just deliberate choice

What you wrote is incorrect. I use the inequality between the arithmetic and the quadratic means, hence the square root. You still need to prove that $a_n \ge a_{n+1}$.

@Gary almost forgot! updated the answer if you're interested

Stolz theorem makes $a_n\to0$.

Suppose $x_n$ is decreasing, then $$\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_k-\frac1{n+1}\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}x_k\
=\frac1{n(n+1)}\left[(n+1)\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_k-n\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}x_k\right]\
=\frac1{n(n+1)}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_k-nx_{n+1}\right)\
=\frac1{n(n+1)}\sum_{k=1}^{n}(x_k-x_{n+1})\geq0.
$$ The arithmetic mean sequence of a decreasing sequence is also decreasing.
